# How to sign my own Arch Linux git packages for adding to a private repo?

Tags: arch-linux, repository, pacman, packaging, pkgbuild

I already have a GPG key configured. I have cloned the git source code package locally. I'm building in a chroot with `extra-x86_64-build`. I am able to build packages *without* signing and add them to the local private repo. Now I want to build the package, **sign it** and add it to my private local repo in a way that will require signature validation on the client when installed with `pacman`.

**What are the steps?**

Below are my current steps, which I assembled from many different Arch wiki pages, man pages, and other places. I include some detail to show what I'm doing and where I'm still having confusion or trouble. Note: I am able to complete all three of the first sections without any issues. My problems start after that.

#### preliminary general steps (all completed):

1. read wiki pages (such as https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Creating_packages)
2. install `base-devel`, `devtools`, `namcap`, `shellcheck`
3. `systemctl status haveged` # make sure it is active

#### preliminary package signing steps (all completed):

- review /usr/share/devtools/pacman-extra.conf

  - I added my local private/custom repository here (with default SigLevel)
- edit /etc/makepkg.conf:

  - `BUILDENV=(!distcc color !ccache check sign)` # make sure `sign` is active
  - `PACKAGER="My Name <me@gmail.com>`"
  - `GPGKEY="1234ABCD09876"` # use your key full fingerprint uppercase, no whitespace
- with an existing GPG key on my user's keyring do these steps:

  - `gpg --armor --output mykey.sec --export-secret-keys 1234ABCD09876`
  - `sudo pacman-key -a mykey.sec`
  - `sudo pacman-key --finger 1234ABCD09876`
  - `sudo pacman-key --lsign-key 1234ABCD09876`

#### prepare source files, PKGBUILD (completed):

1. `git clone ${url}` # or git pull if already cloned
2. inspect PKGBUILD
3. `namcap -i PKGBUILD`
4. `makepkg --packagelist` # inspect version number (optional)

### Questions:

1. FYI - I am starting with internal & trusted source files. They are not signed and there are no sums in the PKGBUILD I start with.
2. how do I modify the PKGBUILD for including sums of the built package and its `.sig` file?

   - at what step is the package's `.sig` file added to the PKGBUILD? How is that done?
3. when are the sums for the built package added to the PKGBUILD?

   - when do I run this step? makepkg -g >> PKGBUILD
   - when is this used instead? updpkgsums

#### next, build the package in a chroot env (I can do this *only without* package signing)

```
`extra-x86\_64-build`
```

NOTE: I am running into this issue: makepkg: fail to sign source package with dynamic version https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=259771 (I guess this will be solved with the next release of pacman? For now, I guess the work-around is to hard-code the version number instead of using VCS-derived versions?)

#### how to add to private repo (I can do this without pkg signing, but I have not succeeded in creating a signed package to test with):

- newpkg="mypackage.r10.918a28e-1-any.pkg.tar.zst" # example
- `namcap -i "$newpkg"`
- `repoctl add --require-signature "$newpkg"`

#### repo questions:

- is the `--require-signature` arg needed in the line above?

Answer (score 2):

Let's assume you've built a package `$pkg` inside `~/build` and want to **sign and then add it to a signed database** named `test_repo`. Here are the steps how you can do it using `gpg` and `repo-add`.

```bash
pkg=some-package-0.0.2-1-any.pkg.tar.zst

# Create a detached signature.
gpg --use-agent --output ~/build/"${pkg}".sig --detach-sig ~/build/"${pkg}" 

# Copy package and its signature to repository directory.
cp ~/build/"${pkg}"{,.sig} ~/repo/

# Add package to repository and sign it.
repo-add --verify --sign ~/repo/test_repo.db.tar.gz ~/repo/"${pkg}"
```

To **install** the package and **test if the signatures work**, you can add the repository to `/etc/pacman.conf`:

```
[test_repo]
SigLevel = Required TrustedOnly
Server = file:///home/YOUR-USERNAME/repo
```

Then run `pacman -Syu` and `pacman -S some-package`.

If your signing key is not yet imported into your pacman keyring, pacman will show you the key-id and ask to import it. Say yes. Then sign the imported key with `sudo pacman-key --lsign <key-id>` and try to install the package again.

**Sources:**

- https://archlinux.org/pacman/makepkg.conf.5.html

  - Using the `--sign` option with `makepkg` overrides the `sign` setting from `makepkg.conf`. "This will execute `gpg --detach-sign --use-agent` on the built package to generate a detached signature file, using the GPG agent, if it is available. The signature file will be the entire file name of the package with a “.sig” extension."
- https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/DeveloperWiki:Package_signing#Arch_implementation

  - "[...] using `repo-add --verify --sign`. [...] Independently of these options, `repo-add` will detect the detached signature, convert it via base64 to ASCII, and add it to the repository database.

---

I have no experience with [repoctl](https://github.com/cassava/repoctl), but I hope the above helps you. Maybe it is enough to create the gpg signature and then run `repoctl add --require-signature ~/build/"${pkg}"`